# Asking the user's goal in the Signup or first time Sign in?

Tags: forms, landing-page, use-cases, sign-in, signup

I want to qualify users in a SaaS product and understand how to bucket these users into use cases. Still, I wonder what's the best moment to add this question and reducing onboarding friction. Is the user psych any different from the sign-up and first-time sign-in?

Answer (score 1):

Anecdotal: Yes. My experience is that people are far less resistant to *voluntary* surveys *after* signup/account creation. If you *need* to have this information before first use of the product/service, it should still be presented as a survey *after* the account has been created. In either case, you should preface the survey (or the request that the user take the survey) with a basic explanation of *why* you want the user to take the survey, and how responding will benefit *the user*.